# Automatically detect if using GUI or batch mode

Tags: path, stata, batch-processing

I am using Stata both in the GUI and running scripts in batch mode using a slurm cluster. The filepaths need to be established differently in each use case but I would like to have one .do file where all of the paths are defined.

Is there a way to write a falsifiable `if` statement that can evaluate to true if run from the GUI and false if run in batch?

Something akin to

```
glob using_gui = T
if $using_gui == T {
    glob dir "/mydir"
} else {
    glob dir "D:/mydir"
}
```

But where `$using_gui` is automatically determined as `T` or `F`

Comment: Cross-posted and answered at https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1634463-automatically-detect-if-using-gui-or-batch-mode It's always a good idea to tell people about cross-posting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered within the statalist question linked above, this can be answered with `c(mode)` so

```
if "`c(mode)'" == "batch" {
    glob dir "/mydir" 
} 
else {
    glob dir "D:/mydir" 
}
```

There are many ways to skin a cat. See `help creturn` for like options.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the GUI on one machine and the batch job on a different machine? If so, you can use `c(username)` for this as the two machines will have different usernames.

For example:

```
if "`c(username)'" == "MyGUILaptop" {
    glob dir "/mydir"
} 
else if "`c(username)'" == "MySlurmCluster" {
    glob dir "D:/mydir"
}
```

You can see the username of the computer you are using by using `` display "`c(username)'" ``. See more about this [here](https://worldbank.github.io/dime-data-handbook/collaboration.html#writing-code-that-others-can-run) (disclaimer: I wrote the book this links to).

Comment: This is a great thought. Unfortunately in my use case, it's the same `username` despite physically being different machines. Neither of which are within my power to rename.